# onPresssed() to navigate to next page not working flutter

Tags: flutter

I use onPresssed() to navigate to next page (details_screen.dart) by clicking card 1. but its throws errors. i think I placed the code in the wrong place. can anyone help to place the code correctly? IN THE CODE I HAVE COMMENTED ON THE CODE BEACUSE ITS NOT WORKING. can anyone please help me on this

> home_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fashion_app/color_filters.dart';
import 'package:fashion_app/details_screen.dart';

 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
    _HomePageState createState ()=> _HomePageState();


  }

class _HomePageState extends State <HomePage> {
  final double _borderRadious = 24;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fashion store'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          buildSearchInput(),
          buildColoredCard1(),
          buildColoredCard2(),
          buildColoredCard3(),


        ],
      ),


    );
  }

  Widget buildSearchInput() => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[200], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 30,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );


  Widget buildColoredCard1() =>
      Card(

        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 8,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.red],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),

          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

            children: [
              Text(

                'Summer Collection',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),


              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              Text(
                'This card is rounded and has a gradient',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,

                ),
                // itemBuilder: (context, index)=>
                //     ItemCard(product:products[index]),


              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

          // onPressed:(){
          //   Navigator.push(
          //       context,
          //       MaterialPageRoute(builder: context)=> const DetailsScreen ());
      );



  }


  Widget buildColoredCard2() =>
      Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 8,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.red],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Winter Collecton',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              Text(
                'This card is rounded and has a gradient',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,

                ),


              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );


  Widget buildColoredCard3() =>
      Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 8,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.red],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Offer',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              Text(
                'This card is rounded and has a gradient',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );


// class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget{
//
//   final
//   }
```

> details_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {


  const DetailsScreen({required Key key,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white70,


    );
  }


  }
```

Comment: Can you uncomment the code and also post the error it shows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GestureDetector widget for navigation, just wrap your card widget with GestureDetector widget.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
       context,
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> const DetailsScreen ());
       );
    },
    child : Card(...) 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a bracket

```
onPressed:(){
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DetailsScreen ());
}
```

Comment: this ), ); not this););  correct it

Answer (score 0):

you are putting semicolon, please compare code, it should be coma not a semicolon

```
onPressed:(){
        Navigator.push(
             context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: context)=> const DetailsScreen 
());

}

  onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DetailsScreen ()),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I check the complete code you are putting two widgets outside the HomPage class and if you want to add on click property you have to wrap your card on any gesture recogniser like GestureDetector, InkWell Please check my code its help you, Thanks
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      _HomePageState createState ()=> _HomePageState();
    
    
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State <HomePage> {
      final double _borderRadious = 24;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Fashion store'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            children: [
              buildSearchInput(),
              buildColoredCard1(),
              buildColoredCard2(),
              buildColoredCard3(),
    
    
            ],
          ),
    
    
        );
      }
    
      Widget buildSearchInput() => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[200], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: 30,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    
    
      Widget buildColoredCard1() =>
          InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> DetailScreen()));
            },
            child: Card(
              shadowColor: Colors.red,
              elevation: 8,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
              ),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.red],
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
    
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    
                  children: [
                    Text(
    
                      'Summer Collection',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 28,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
    
    
                    const SizedBox(height: 50),
                    Text(
                      'This card is rounded and has a gradient',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
    
                      ),
                      // itemBuilder: (context, index)=>
                      //     ItemCard(product:products[index]),
    
    
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
    
              // onPressed:(){
              //   Navigator.push(
              //       context,
              //       MaterialPageRoute(builder: context)=> const DetailsScreen ());
            ),
          );
      Widget buildColoredCard2() =>
          Card(
            shadowColor: Colors.red,
            elevation: 8,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
            ),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.red],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Winter Collecton',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 28,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  Text(
                    'This card is rounded and has a gradient',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
    
                    ),
    
    
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
    
    
      Widget buildColoredCard3() =>
          Card(
            shadowColor: Colors.red,
            elevation: 8,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
            ),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.red],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Offer',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  Text(
                    'This card is rounded and has a gradient',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
    
    }
    
    
    class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const DetailScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
    }
    
    class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
    
    
        );
      }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget{
    //
    //   final
    //   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to navigate. Do not forget the spaces, brackets and semicolons. They are so important!

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Design1()));
                    },
```

Answer (score -1):

there is ( missed

```
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
                                const DetailsScreen()),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).